# Modified toom-cook algorithm

Tags: algorithms, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

1. For [these transformation matrices generated using modified toom-cook algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10986v1.pdf#page=9) , **why** are they different compared to the following transformation matrices in the picture below ?

> We can solve the smaller problem using M′(x) where deg(M′(x))
> = deg(M(x))−1 and just add the missing value. With this approach we need n−1 points instead of n used in Section 3.1 for generating matrices suitable for the same size of computed convolution

2. In section 5 on page 7, why does author claim that his modified toom-cook algorithm only requires n-1 points ? How exactly *deg(M′(x)) = deg(M(x))−1* is relevant in proving modified toom-cook algorithm ? There is not much explanation (Algorithm 8.2.2) on page 249/234 inside reference [10] : [VLSI Digital Signal Processing Systems: Design and Implementation](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CBADFCB56649EA1ECF20DDABAF2A719F)

[image: winograd matrices]

Comment: @Moo you mean [VLSI Digital Signal Processing Systems: Design and Implementation](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CBADFCB56649EA1ECF20DDABAF2A719F) ?

Comment: @Moo Have a look at Algorithm 8.2.2 on page 249 of the book.

Comment: @Moo What did you exactly mean by "cannot seem to get it from that link" ?

Comment: @Moo There are multiple mirrors (Gen.lib.rus.ec, Libgen.lc, Z-Library, Libgen.pw, BookFI.net). If still cannot, use this [direct download link](http://93.174.95.29/main/342000/cbadfcb56649ea1ecf20ddabaf2a719f/Keshab%20K.%20Parhi%20-%20VLSI%20Digital%20Signal%20Processing%20Systems_%20Design%20and%20Implementation-Wiley-Interscience%20%281999%29.djvu)

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Modified toom-cook algorithm](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368713)